# Null string as place holder in Teradata query

Tags: sql, null, teradata, placeholder, temporary

I am hitting a Teradata database and then taking the data and pumping that into a SQL server database. All is working well except right now the TD db doesn't have one string field implemented just yet so am using a null as a place holder.

```
select 
mac.Company "CompanyName",  
mac.VEHICLE_ID "CarNo", 
null "AmzCode"
```

Doing some testing I realized that returns an integer field with a null. Im assuming here that the default data type is always an integer if not defined.

So changed to:

```
select 
mac.Company "CompanyName",  
mac.VEHICLE_ID "CarNo", 
cast(null as varchar(4)) "AmzCode"
```

Is that the sound way to do a place holder that will be a null string until such time the TD field gets implemented?

Comment: You are much better off being explicit about the type.  I know `NULL` defaults to an `int` in SQL Server.  I don't know if Teradata follows the same rules.

Comment: thanks. i was explicit ad I think that works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I just did some quick testing and it looks like Teradata defaults to Integer as well.

Comment: thanks for the info. I think I understand now how to make the field a proper string placeholder.